# How to plot multiple series using Jenkins plot plugin with an xml file

Tags: xml, plugins, xpath, jenkins, plot

I have an xml file in below format:

```
<summary>
    <start>2013-12-03 12:24:35,785</start>
    <end>2013-12-03 12:34:34,107</end>
    <duration unit="minutes">10</duration>
    <transactions>2716</transactions>
    <throughput unit="Transactions per second">4.53</throughput>
    <APIs>
        <API name=" USER_LOGIN">
            <mean>687.4</mean>
            <median>603</median>
            <stdDev>308.71</stdDev>
            <minimum>553</minimum>
            <maximum>2009</maximum>
            <count>57/2716 (2.1%)</count>
            <successCount>57</successCount>
            <failureCount>0</failureCount>
        </API>
        <API name=" APP_SETTINGS_GET">
            <mean>496.23</mean>
            <median>474</median>
            <stdDev>53.94</stdDev>
            <minimum>446</minimum>
            <maximum>704</maximum>
            <count>57/2716 (2.1%)</count>
            <successCount>57</successCount>
            <failureCount>0</failureCount>
        </API>
    </APIs>
</summary>
```

With the above xml, I need to plot all the "mean" nodes present inside "API" nodes in one graph in Jenkins plot plugin. Could anyone please help me in constructing the xpath for getting all "mean" nodes?

Thanks,
Mamatha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `/summary/APIs/API/mean`, but I'm pretty sure you'll just get two series, both named "mean", which is pretty meaningless.

Alternatively if what you want from the example above is two series, one named "USER_LOGIN" and the other "APP_SETTINGS_GET", you can just turn the Xml into a CSV file and have the plugin use that.  If you're on Windows this Powershell script would do it (assuming your Xml is in `input.xml`):

```ps
$csvObject = New-Object PSObject
Select-Xml -Path input.xml -Xpath "/summary/APIs/API" | 
    select -ExpandProperty node | 
    For-Each { Add-Member -InputObject $csvObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.name -Value $_.mean }
Export-Csv -Path means.csv -InputObject $csvObject -NoTypeInformation
```

This just generates a CSV file that looks like this:

```
"USER_LOGIN","APP_SETTINGS_GET"
"687.4","496.23"
```

Then you import it as a CSV series:

[image: Importing the CSV file in the Jenkins plot plugin]